# Speed up for loop assigning data to matrix in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, matrix

I am simulating data and filling a matrix using a for loop in R. Currently the loop is running slower than I would like. I've done some work to vectorize some of the variables to improve the loops speed but it still taking some time.  I believe the

```
mat[j,year] <- sum(vec==1)/x
```

part of the loop is slowing things down. I've looked into filling matrices more efficiently but could not find anything to help my current problem. Eventually this will be used as a part of a shiny app so all of variables I assign will need to be easily assigned different values.

Any advice to speed up the loop or more efficiently write this loop would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the loop:

```
#These variables are all specified because they need to change with different simulations

num.sims <- 20 
time <- 50
mat <- matrix(nrow = num.sims, ncol = time)
x <- 1000
init <- 0.5*x  
vec <- vector(length = x)
ratio <- 1 
freq <- -0.4 
freq.vec <- numeric(nrow(mat))

## start a loop
for (j in 1:num.sims) {

vec[1:init] <- 1; vec[(init+1):x] <- 2
year <- 2

freq.vec[j] <- sum(vec==1)/x


for (i in 1:(x*(time-1))) {

freq.1 <- sum(vec==1)/x; freq.2 <- 1 - freq.1
fit.ratio <- exp(freq*(freq.1-0.5) + log(ratio))
Pr.1 <- fit.ratio*freq.1/(fit.ratio*freq.1 + freq.2)
vec[ceiling(x*runif(1))] <- sample(c(1,2), 1, prob=c(Pr.1,1-Pr.1))

## record data    
if (i %% x == 0) {
  mat[j,year] <- sum(vec==1)/x
  year <- year + 1
}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop is what is slowing you down. You're doing `x` number of iterations to update each cell in the matrix. Since each trip to modify `vec` depends on the previous iteration, this would be difficult to simplify. @Andrew Feierman is probably correct that this would benefit from being moved to C++, at least the four lines before the `if` statement.

Alternatively, this only takes 10-20 seconds to run. Unless you're going to scale this up or run it many times, it might not be worth the trouble to speed it up. If you do keep it as is, you could put a progress bar in Shiny to let the user know things are still working.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how often you will need to call this loop, it could be worth rewriting it in C++. R is built on C++, and any C++ will run many, many times faster than even efficient R code.

sourceCpp is a good package to start with: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rcpp/versions/0.12.11/topics/sourceCpp